# How to create Stacked and Grouped column graph in an inner drilldown?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

with the use number of examples, I am trying to create the stacked and grouped chart in  drill down (inner chart), but at a time only single chart display (stacked or grouped)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by loading drilldown stacked series in drilldown event using `chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown()` for each series you want to display and next call `chart.applyDrilldown()`. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
$(function() {

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
          if (!e.seriesOptions) {
            var chart = this,
              drilldowns = {
                'Animals1': {
                  name: 'Animals',
                  stack: 'sortA',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                  data: [
                    ['Cows', 2],
                    ['Sheep', 3]
                  ]
                },
                'Animals2': {
                  name: 'Animals',
                  stack: 'sortA',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                  data: [
                    ['Cows', 12],
                    ['Sheep', 10]
                  ]
                },
                'Animals3': {
                  name: 'Animals',
                  stack: 'sortB',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                  data: [
                    ['Cows', 15],
                    ['Sheep', 6]
                  ]
                },
                'Animals4': {
                  name: 'Animals',
                  stack: 'sortB',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                  data: [
                    ['Cows', 2],
                    ['Sheep', 11]
                  ]
                },
                'Fruits1': {
                  name: 'Fruits',
                  stack: 'sortA',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                  data: [
                    ['Apples', 5],
                    ['Oranges', 1],
                    ['Bananas', 4]
                  ]
                },
                'Fruits2': {
                  name: 'Fruits',
                  stack: 'sortA',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                  data: [
                    ['Apples', 15],
                    ['Oranges', 11],
                    ['Bananas', 22]
                  ]
                },
                'Fruits3': {
                  name: 'Fruits',
                  stack: 'sortB',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                  data: [
                    ['Apples', 12],
                    ['Oranges', 7],
                    ['Bananas', 6]
                  ]
                },
                'Fruits4': {
                  name: 'Fruits',
                  stack: 'sortB',
                  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                  data: [
                    ['Apples', 15],
                    ['Oranges', 17],
                    ['Bananas', 9]
                  ]
                },
              },
              i;

            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
              chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(
                e.point,
                drilldowns[e.point.name + i]
              );
            }

            chart.applyDrilldown();
          }

        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Things',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'Animals',
        y: 5,
        drilldown: true
      }, {
        name: 'Fruits',
        y: 2,
        drilldown: true
      }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
      series: []
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sdxprb3o/